# E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed in headless mode

Tags: angularjs, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

Face the following error

- Google Chrome - 67.0
- chromedriver - chromedriver_2.40
- selenium standalone - selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar
- linux - CentOS Linux release 7.3
- Protractor - 5.1.2
- Nodejs - v6.14.2

config.ts

```
chrome: {
        seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
        directConnect: true,
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions:{
        args: ['--headless','--disable-gpu','--disable-dev-shm-usage','--no-sandbox','window-size=1024,768']
    }
```

> 10:37:07.923 [10:37:07] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
>   10:37:07.923 [10:37:07] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
>   10:38:09.409 [10:38:09] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
>   10:38:09.409   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   10:38:09.409 Command duration or timeout: 60.39 seconds
>   10:38:09.409 Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z'
>   10:38:09.409 System info: host: 'sigmagoagt-po-a1p.sys.comcast.net', ip: '147.191.72.189', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
>   10:38:09.410 Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>   10:38:09.410 [10:38:09] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
>   10:38:09.410   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   10:38:09.410 Command duration or timeout: 60.39 seconds
>   10:38:09.410 Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z'
>   10:38:09.411 System info: host: 'sigmagoagt-po-a1p.sys.comcast.net', ip: '147.191.72.189', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
>   10:38:09.411 Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>   10:38:09.411     at WebDriverError (/app/go-agent1/pipelines/UI-Automation-Testing/web/client-portal/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
>   10:38:09.411     at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/app/go-agent1/pipelines/UI-Automation-Testing/web/client-portal/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505:15)
>   10:38:09.411     at parseHttpResponse (/app/go-agent1/pipelines/UI-Automation-Testing/web/client-portal/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
>   10:38:09.412     at doSend.then.response (/app/go-agent1/pipelines/UI-Automation-Testing/web/client-portal/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:440:13)
>   10:38:09.412     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
>   10:38:09.412 From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
>   10:38:09.412     at Function.createSession (/app/go-agent1/pipelines/UI-Automation-Testing/web/client-portal/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:777:24)
>   10:38:09.412     at Function.createSession (/app/go-agent1/pipelines/UI-Automation-Testing/web/client-portal/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:709:29)
>   10:38:09.412     at createDriver (/app/go-agent1/pipelines/UI-Automation-Testing/web/client-portal/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:167:33)
>   10:38:09.412     at Builder.build (/app/go-agent1/pipelines/UI-Automation-Testing/web/client-portal/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:623:16)
>   10:38:09.413     at Hosted.getNewDriver (/app/go-agent1/pipelines/UI-Automation-Testing/web/client-portal/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/driverProvider.ts:60:29)
>   10:38:09.413     at Runner.createBrowser (/app/go-agent1/pipelines/UI-Automation-Testing/web/client-portal/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:225:39)
>   10:38:09.413     at q.then.then (/app/go-agent1/pipelines/UI-Automation-Testing/web/client-portal/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:391:27)
>   10:38:09.413     at _fulfilled (/app/go-agent1/pipelines/UI-Automation-Testing/web/client-portal/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
>   10:38:09.413     at self.promiseDispatch.done (/app/go-agent1/pipelines/UI-Automation-Testing/web/client-portal/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
>   10:38:09.413     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/app/go-agent1/pipelines/UI-Automation-Testing/web/client-portal/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
>   10:38:09.414     at /app/go-agent1/pipelines/UI-Automation-Testing/web/client-portal/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
>   10:38:09.414     at runSingle (/app/go-agent1/pipelines/UI-Automation-Testing/web/client-portal/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
>   10:38:09.414     at flush (/app/go-agent1/pipelines/UI-Automation-Testing/web/client-portal/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
>   10:38:09.414     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
>   10:38:09.414     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling and re-installation of Chrome in centOS machine solved the issue. Followed installation procedure available in "https://intoli.com/blog/installing-google-chrome-on-centos/". Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can run tests using selenium server or run them directly on browser. You should remove one of :

```
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
```

or

```
directConnect: true,
```